# Is there a R package to generate a .ris file based on a query in a data bases?

Tags: r, export-to-csv

For a **scoping study**/systematic literature review I would like a **package which generates a reference list as a .ris file directly from publisher data bases** such as Wiley, PubMed, Science Direct Web of Science and JSTOR.

Is there a package (or a workaround with API) that can "output" all listed resources of a **database query as a file / dataframe in R?**

I have read about "refwork" and "revtools" so far, but they seem to need .ris data upfront. I am looking for something generating me this file and not me doing this individually (which means ticking results page for page and exporting it).